# Project with Mahapps.Metro doesn't run on different computer

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro

I have a problem where my program, which uses the Mahapps.Metro controls won't start on a different computer.

It seems like when my friend opens my program, it runs, but no window appears.

Is there something I've completely missed?

(I've copied my project-folder and sent it to him, and he has opened the .exe located in the Debugfolder)

Comment: are you shure that the MahApps Dll is also present in your debug folder? How did you include the library?

Comment: Might there is no problem with Mahapps, and there is one somewhere else?

Comment: @roqz The Mahapps dll fils is present, yes. I added the package from NuGet.

Comment: @AgentFire I don't know where the problem might be then. It's just really weird since I can move the Debugfolder to some destination on my computer and still run it, perfectly. But on my friends computer it doesn't work.

Comment: I now have no idea what to do, I tested it on another computer and it's still the same. The weird thing is that the process shows up in the taskmanager for a few seconds, then it disappears (still no window showing up). Even though I've commented out all the code my program does at startup.

Comment: So there can't be a problem with hard-coded paths (and believe me, I've checked for those.)

Answer (score 0):

Clean up MahApps and MahApps Resources using NuGet and the fully re-install those packages.